# Indexing function for dynamic arrays in c

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am writing this piece of code which works without any errors but when I run it with `valgrind` it throws errors that `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value` which is caused by the `while` loop trying to access the third element in the array

My question is can I use the function `get_index()` since it does not show any warnings or errors when compiling with `gcc -g -Wall -pedantic main.c`  and outputs the same index as the `idx` which is declared globally

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L 3 

int *ptr;
int idx=0; // index

int get_index()
{
  int x=0;
  while(ptr[x])
    x++;
  return x;
}


void add_elem()
{
  printf("Enter your number :\n");
  scanf("%d",&ptr[idx]);
  idx++;
}


int main(void) {
  ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

  add_elem();
  add_elem();

  printf("Current index : %d\n",get_index());
  printf("Original index : %d\n",idx);
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have allocated single `int` and you can't write to unalloacted memory. and in `get_index` termination of `while-loop` is not correct. `get_index` can't give the current index use another variable to track it

Comment: You allocate space for a single `int` value. Which means the only valid index into your array is `0`. Your program go out of bounds, and will have *undefined behavior*. While you allocate memory dynamically, once allocated the size is fixed.

Comment: How come I don't get any errors other than in valgrind

Comment: [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/4139593)